# CustomListView : Image is changing when scrolling a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I know that this question is asked many times..
 But I cant get any proper solution, In my app I use `AsyncTask` for loading a image. 
 I use `AsyncTask` because I want smooth scrolling listview.. and after implement `AsyncTask` My listView get smoothly scrolling..
 But now problem is that Image is changing after scrolling...
 What should I do?

MyAdapter Class

```
package com.example.adapter;
public class DisplayAllFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DisplayAllFeedItem> {
    private final List<DisplayAllFeedItem> list;
    private final Activity context;
    ExifInterface exif;

    public DisplayAllFeedAdapter(Activity context, List<DisplayAllFeedItem> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.feed_screen, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView optionalDesc, reportedBy;
        public LinearLayout layout;
        public ImageView displayFeedimg, channelIcon;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_all_feed_listitem, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.optionalDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFeedOptionalDesc);
            viewHolder.reportedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFeedReportedBy);
            viewHolder.displayFeedimg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgFeedDisplayImage);
            viewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutChannelImgView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView.setTag(R.id.txtFeedOptionalDesc, viewHolder.optionalDesc);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.txtFeedReportedBy, viewHolder.reportedBy);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.imgFeedDisplayImage, viewHolder.displayFeedimg);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.layoutChannelImgView, viewHolder.layout);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String temp;
        String drawableImagePath = list.get(position).getMediaChannelName();
        List<String> channelList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (drawableImagePath.length() > 0) {

            if (drawableImagePath.indexOf(",") == -1) {
                temp = drawableImagePath.substring(0);
                channelList.add(temp);
                break;
            } else {
                temp = drawableImagePath.substring(0, drawableImagePath.indexOf(","));
            }
            channelList.add(temp);
            drawableImagePath = drawableImagePath.substring(drawableImagePath.indexOf(",") + 1);
        }
        viewHolder.layout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < channelList.size(); i++) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(30),
                    dpToPx(30));
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(channelList.get(i)));
            viewHolder.layout.addView(imageView);
        }

        String tempPath = list.get(position).getMediaPath();
        File mediaFile = new File(tempPath);
        Bitmap bitmap;

            viewHolder.optionalDesc.setText(list.get(position).getMediaDesc());
        viewHolder.reportedBy.setText("Reported By " + list.get(position).getMediaDisplayName());
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            new LoadImage(viewHolder).execute(tempPath);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

        // File mediaFile = new File(tempPath);
        Bitmap bitmap, displayBitmap;
        File mediaFile;
        String mediaPath;
        private final ViewHolder imageViewReference;

        public LoadImage(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            imageViewReference = viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            // File f = new File(params[0]);
            mediaPath = params[0];

            mediaFile = new File(mediaPath);
            if (mediaFile.exists()) {
                if (isImage(mediaPath)) {
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    int height = (myBitmap.getHeight() * 512 / myBitmap.getWidth());
                    Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 512, height, true);
                    int rotate = 0;

                    try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                    switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        rotate = 0;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                    }

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                    displayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scale, 0, 0, scale.getWidth(),
                            scale.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                } else {
                    displayBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaPath,
                            Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

                }

            }
            return displayBitmap;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                imageViewReference.displayFeedimg.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
            // tempView.displayFeedimg.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    }

    public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }

    public static boolean isImage(String str) {
        boolean temp = false;
        String[] arr = { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = str.endsWith(arr[i]);
            if (temp) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Picasso library and save time http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: you can also use [Aquery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

Comment: Can you make sure that you're getting the correct bitmap (displayBitmap) from doInBackground method?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on your problem (need better clarification) but I know there are issues on loading images about the lag in performance.

Please Look at Google's web [Making a Standard Request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html).
Search for (Universal) Image Loader, text "Use ImageLoader and NetworkImageView".
You can further improve performance by caching, located below that text.

Code snippet from the webpage:

```
ImageLoader mImageLoader;
ImageView mImageView;
// The URL for the image that is being loaded.
private static final String IMAGE_URL =
    "http://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";
...
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.regularImageView);

// Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
mImageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView,
         R.drawable.def_image, R.drawable.err_image));
```

There seems a good tutorial in [Solving the Android image loading problem...](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/) by a knowledgeable author.
Have fun with this. And someday I may have to solve this problem as well. Pls keep us posted.

Comment: My Main issue is that when I m scrolling my listview, image of listview is changed..

Comment: Can you make sure that you're getting the correct bitmap from doInBackground method?

Answer (score 0):

Besides my previous answer, there is another possible solution. But it is somewhat different than Google's recommendation, so beware...

Look at Stackoverflow discussion [ListView like in universal image loader sample app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941128/listview-like-in-universal-image-loader-sample-app). Checkout code in that page. In CarListAdapter:

```
ImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
```

...In another method:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(...);
```

Both of my answers lead to one point, use the (Universal) Image Loader.