# animation not smooth on high density devices

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I'm having trouble Fragment setCustomAnimations on higher density android devices.

I'm doing the flip card animation.
On mdpi and hpid devices the animation is very smooth.
However on xhdpi, xxhdi, and xxxhdpi devices the animation works but it looks like it skips a few frames.

I'm using this code for fragment transition.

Here is the in animation

```
<!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="0"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />

<!-- Rotate. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="180"
    android:valueTo="0" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="250"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
<!-- Rescale in -->
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:startOffset="250"
    android:valueFrom="0.60"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:startOffset="250"
    android:valueFrom="0.60"
    android:valueTo="1.0" />
```

Here is the out animation

```
<!-- Rotate. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-180" />

<!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:startOffset="250"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.0" />
<!-- Rescale out -->
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.60" />
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueFrom="1.0"
    android:valueTo="0.60" />
```

Even if I take the scale animation out it still looks much smoother on an mdpi and hdpi devices.

Answer (score 0):

I posted 2 lengthy answers on a similar question just today. I'll refer you to  [...Image is changing when scrolling a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850368/customlistview-image-is-changing-when-scrolling-a-listview/28862824#28862824).

It seems you have everything else working. Keep us posted, especially since I may have this problem in the near future. For me, I'll have to monitor both posts, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I found this animation skipped a few frames for me but this improved it quite a lot:

```
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
```

Also consider if your animation becomes less smooth on higher res device it could be that you have an image that is getting scaled too big, taking up lots of memory and slowing things down - i experienced this myself when i placed a large high res image in the "drawable" folder thinking that no scaling would be applied (this folder should generally only be used for resources specified with xml), but in fact it gets treated as though it is mdpi image and hence the unwanted scaling up on higher res devices can kill the performance of your animation